# Query Resources in Resources

Tags: soql, sobject

Is there any way I can query the Resources in `Public Calendars and Resources`? There does not seem to be any object related to the resources so if someone could help me out, it'd be great!

Comment: It can not be queried...the object is not exposed by Salesforce...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. And Adrian, I did see that post but was wondering (actually hoping) that there'd be something for the Resources if not the Calendars

Comment: I recommend you [edit] your post to be specific to that then and I will retract my close vote. :)

Comment: It's edited! :)